# Railway network graphs

Tags: java, networking, graph

Do you know about some library of graphs (railway network graphs) on the Internet, which I can use for simulating? It don't have to be graphical, but it could. I am looking for real (almost real) graphs of railway network. Graphs should contain distances between places. I would like to use these graphs in Java SE.

Comment: In what format? How many stations?

Comment: For example .txt, it does not matter and the number of stations - for example some graphs with the less number of stations (50) and some graphs with more stations (number of stations of Europe).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use data from OpenStreetMaps. It is stored in xml format. Just download *.osm file of some region and select only railways. Railways have type "way" in xml and attributes "railway"="rail".
Here is an example of such data:

```
<node version="7" lon="45.9502925" lat="51.5942789" ... id="344372532"/>
<node version="7" lon="45.9505103" lat="51.5945062" ... id="344372533"/>
<node version="7" lon="45.950933" lat="51.594687" ... id="344372534"/> 

<way version="6" changeset="6856374"visible="true" user="lamaur"uid="377142"timestamp="2011-01-03T23:42:49Z"id="34895610">
    <nd ref="919804950"/>
    <nd ref="919805175"/>
    ...
    <nd ref="409244123"/>
    <tag v="rail" k="railway"/>
    <tag v="spur" k="service"/>
</way>
```

**upd**

Map data sepparated by regions is available at http://downloads.cloudmade.com/

Comment: But you can download only very small area from http://www.openstreetmap.org, is there any option have to download railway of the Europe?

Comment: Yes, there are archives containg all data of a single country, for example. I'll try to find some.

Comment: I belive that tools exist also that can help to download only specific data types (e.g. railways), but a can't find any yet.

Answer (score 0):

Check [JUNG](http://jung.sourceforge.net/). Beside excellent graphics options, it is bundled with a bunch of algorithms to find weighted and unweighted shortest paths. You can even calculate the maximum flow in a graph where the edges have a capacity.

Comment: It is great, but I am looking for data.

Comment: But on the other hand JUNG is very good tool, maybe I will use it in the future. Thank you.